# How to control the files that Release Management copies when the Deployment Agents runs a Component

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-release-management

I am using MS Release Management and Agent-based deployments. My templates generally deploy a web site along with a database in a single template.  I've also added a few scripts to the Inventory that I utilize in the release templates.

What I've noticed is that with some of the built-in components and the scripts that I've added, RM Server copies the entire TfsBuidDrop to the Deployment Agent's workspace on the target server, for each component in the template.

For example, the component to Publish a Database is a simple tool that updates a database using the .dacpac for the database.  The component is configured to use the .dacpac file and a couple of other parameters to do it's thing.  If I look at the RM Agent workspace on the target server, I see that the entire TfsBuildDrop folder gets copied to this component's workspace even though the Agent needs only the single .dacpac file.

I noticed the same behavior with the components I created for the scripts I'm using.  The entire TfsBuildDrop folder is being copied to the target server for each component in the release template.

Is there a way to limit the files that the RM Server copies to the Target server?  For some of my release templates, the entire build-drop folder gets copied to the server 5-6 times for each deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an issue of how you organize your build. If you specify `\` in your component as the path to your component's binaries, it will recursively copy the entire build drop folder. This is 100% by design.

Write a quick Powershell script and run it as a post-build step to copy, say, *.dacpac to a `\DACPAC\` folder. Then you can point your component to that folder instead, and it will only copy those files.

Comment: I get the concept of controlling the output to the build drop folder and pointing the component to a folder instead of the root.  My powershell isn't very good yet.  Would you have a small sample script to copy a file?  How do you reference the build drop folder?